# get the value of Template variables from the span to button in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I was trying to access value from span to button from the template variable.

```html
<button 
   class="btn btn-primary "
   (click)="editAction(action)">
<span  #action id="action" 
   class="">{{data?.approve ? 'Approve':'Delete'}}</span>
</button>
```

I am not able to access the action variable using the template reference variable.

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: I am using angular 10

Comment: You should read more carefully: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables. In the above code you are creating a variable called `action` but you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: i'm not sure why you are trying to get the span value since it is based on the data.approve. you can access data.approve in the ts file.

Comment: Yes, I can access data directly in ts file.. was looking for any better approach than this..

Comment: Accessing `data.approve` directly in the ts file is the better approach. I don't see the benefit of sending back a value from the template to controller that's already available in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

This [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mnnmky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) shows it working. You should be able have access with no issues to it by doing something like:

```
editAction(action: HTMLElement) {
  console.log(action.innerText);
}
```